# MySQL, how to fetch from two tables and one more time with different ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and post.

Tables are paper, subject, some post content saved and opened in subject page.

Here issue is paper ID is Common but Subject ID changes for multiple posts.

```
$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tut_blog_posts WHERE paper_name='".$results_paper["id"]."' AND subject_name='".$results_subject["id"]."' ORDER BY postID DESC");
```

Sometime data works and other times the same paper ID and Subject ID don't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: you said fetch from 2 table but why your query only from 1 table? and by öne time only data working" means it work the 1st time but not 2nd time? can u reword it so its easier for me to understand.

Comment: yes one table ,yes first time and not second time

Comment: so what is your problem? you fail/want to fetch from 2 table? or that you're having problems for the second time? and can u show us more codes? if the query works the 1st time then it might not be your queries fault.

Comment: how to fetch data same paper id and different subject ID